# keras.utils.to_categorical() - name keras not defined

Tags: python, keras

I am running the test script from the [Keras website](https://keras.io/getting-started/sequential-model-guide/) for Multilayer Perceptron (MLP) for multi-class softmax classification.  Running in the jupyter notebook I get the error "name 'keras' is not defined".  This may be a simple python syntax problem that I am not keen to, however this code comes straight from keras so I expect it should work as is.  I have run other neural nets using keras, so I am pretty sure that I have installed everything (installed keras using anaconda).  Can anyone help?  I have included both the code and the error at the bottom.  Thanks!

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation
from keras.optimizers import SGD

# Generate dummy data
import numpy as np
x_train = np.random.random((1000, 20))
y_train = keras.utils.to_categorical(np.random.randint(10, size=(1000, 1)), num_classes=10)
x_test = np.random.random((100, 20))
y_test = keras.utils.to_categorical(np.random.randint(10, size=(100, 1)), num_classes=10)

model = Sequential()
# Dense(64) is a fully-connected layer with 64 hidden units.
# in the first layer, you must specify the expected input data shape:
# here, 20-dimensional vectors.
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu', input_dim=20))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))

sgd = SGD(lr=0.01, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer=sgd,
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train,
          epochs=20,
          batch_size=128)
score = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, batch_size=128)
```

This is the error message:

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-6d8174e3cf2a> in <module>()
      6 import numpy as np
      7 x_train = np.random.random((1000, 20))
----> 8 y_train = keras.utils.to_categorical(np.random.randint(10, size=(1000, 1)), num_classes=10)
      9 x_test = np.random.random((100, 20))
     10 y_test = keras.utils.to_categorical(np.random.randint(10, size=(100, 1)), num_classes=10)

NameError: name 'keras' is not defined
```

Comment: Maybe `import keras`? Or `from keras.utils import to_categorical`?

Comment: @devforfu Both work! Please post as an answer I can image I wont be the only one having this problem.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation
from keras.optimizers import SGD
```

From above, you only imported following submodules in `keras`

- `keras.models`
- `keras.layers`
- `keras.optimizers`

But this does not automatically import the outer module like `keras`
or other submodules `keras.utils`

So, you can do either one

```
import keras
import keras.utils
from keras import utils as np_utils
```

but `from keras import utils as np_utils` is the most widely used.

Especially `import keras` is not a good practice because importing the higher module does not necessarily import its submodules (though it works in Keras)

For example,

`import urllib`
does not necessarily import `urllib.request` because if there are so many big submodules, it's inefficient to import all of its submodules every time.

**EDIT:**
With the introduction of Tensorflow 2, keras submodules such as `keras.utils` should now be imported as

```
from tensorflow.keras import utils as np_utils
```

Comment: Adding `tensorflow.` keyword before all `keras` es, solved all the errors for me, in Tensorflow 2.

Answer (score 9):

General way:

```
from keras.utils import to_categorical
Y_train = to_categorical(y_train, num_classes)
```

Concrete way:

```
from keras.utils import to_categorical

print(to_categorical(1, 2))
print(to_categorical(0, 2))
```

Will output

```
[0. 1.]
[1. 0.]
```

Answer (score 8):

Although this is an old question but yet updating the latest approach to access to_categorical function.

This function has now been packed in np_utils.

The correct way to access it is:

```
from keras.utils.np_utils import to_categorical
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from keras import utils as np_utils 

 y_train =  tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes)
 y_test = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test, num_classes)
```