# How to resolve keras.callbacks import errors for TensorBoard?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorboard

**Attempt 1**

```
from keras.callbacks import TensorBoard

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras import layers
from keras.optimizers import RMSprop
tb_callback = keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir="/Users/baldur009/Documents/Scripts/log/model_gru", histogram_freq=0, write_graph=True, write_images=True)

model = Sequential()
model.add(layers.GRU(10, input_shape=(None, ts_matrix.shape[-1])))
model.add(layers.Dense(1))
model.compile(optimizer=RMSprop(), loss='mae')
history = model.fit_generator(train_gen,
                          steps_per_epoch=30,
                          epochs=30,
                          validation_data=val_gen,
                          validation_steps=val_steps, callbacks=[tb_callback])
```

Error:

```
NameError                                
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-c43bea5e24d5> in <module>()
  2 from keras import layers
  3 from keras.optimizers import RMSprop
----> 4 tb_callback = keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir="/Users/baldur009/Documents/Scripts/log/pertussis_gru", histogram_freq=0, write_graph=True, write_images=True)
  5 
  6 model = Sequential()

NameError: name 'keras' is not defined
```

**Attempt 2**

Removed

```
keras.callbacks
```

So that:

```
tb_callback = TensorBoard(log_dir="/Users/catherineordun/Documents/Scripts/log/pertussis_gru", histogram_freq=0, write_graph=True, write_images=True)
```

I received the following error upon running:

```
---> 22 from tensorflow.contrib import bayesflow
 23 from tensorflow.contrib import cloud
 24 from tensorflow.contrib import compiler

ImportError: cannot import name bayesflow
```

As a result, searched and found https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/10811

```
conda update dask
```

Continue to receive the same error:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-48-c43bea5e24d5> in <module>()
  2 from keras import layers
  3 from keras.optimizers import RMSprop
----> 4 tb_callback = keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir="/Users/baldur009/Documents/Scripts/log/pertussis_gru", histogram_freq=0, write_graph=True, write_images=True)
  5 
  6 model = Sequential()

 /Users/baldur009/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/callbacks.pyc in __init__(self, log_dir, histogram_freq, batch_size, write_graph, write_grads, write_images, embeddings_freq, embeddings_layer_names, embeddings_metadata)
641         global tf, projector
642         import tensorflow as tf
--> 643         from tensorflow.contrib.tensorboard.plugins import projector
644         self.log_dir = log_dir
645         self.histogram_freq = histogram_freq

/Users/baldur009/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/__init__.py in <module>()
 20 
 21 # Add projects here, they will show up under tf.contrib.
---> 22 from tensorflow.contrib import bayesflow
 23 from tensorflow.contrib import cloud
 24 from tensorflow.contrib import compiler

ImportError: cannot import name bayesflow
```

So, I read: [keras.utils.to_categorical() - name keras not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44054082/keras-utils-to-categorical-name-keras-not-defined), and therefore imported the following to cover as many dependencies as possible:

```
import keras
import keras.callbacks
from keras.callbacks import TensorBoard
```

But, continued to face same error.

Answer (score 0):

After waiting five minutes and restarting the Jupyter (restart & clear output), it now runs.